# Subdomains as external backlinks

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, backlinks

as far as I know backlinks are good for SEO when they come from external or websites or domains, what about subdomain? do they have the same value of external backlinks or they are just like internal ones? especially when I have the possibility to put each subdomain on a different IP/country

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overlooked the most important thing: links are judged by many factors with the most critical ones being the strength of the page the link is on. If the page is off topic and/or poorly ranked whether it is on a subdomain, same domain, or external site really doesn't mean anything as a link from that page won't be worth anything significant. (Other factors include quantity of links of the page and anchor text of the links). So even if you spread your content around like that it won't matter if those pages are poor quality (SEO wise).

Having said that, [Google doesn't see subdomains as anything different from subfolders](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/) so these links would be seen as residing on the same website.

I guess while I'm at it, don't underestimate the power of internal linking. If you have a large enough site and interlink your pages properly you can give yourself a nice SEO boost. It does wonders for Wikipedia. They do a perfect job of interlinking their internal pages with minor pages reaping the rewards of the links from other pages that have lots of incoming links, etc.

Comment: Yes I really noticed that Wikipedia is pofiting from interlinking but some people told me that interlinking is not a good idea for SEO

Comment: Stop listening to whomever told you that. That is very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very wrong.

Comment: do you have any tips/references for good interlinking practices?

Comment: @Andy, Crosslink your pages as often as possible. If you have a page that covers a topic that you mention in your content then link to it. It's good usability as it helps users know more about the topic and it's obviously good SEO.

Comment: John, you say that Google does not see subdomain as anything different from subfolders, but when I read the post, there is nothing confirming this in it...?!??

Answer (score 0):

[It depends whether you own the root domain or not](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2011/08/reorganizing-internal-vs-external.html). If you do, the backlink of the subdomain will count as an internal link. If you don't, it will count as an external link.